# Setting tcolorbox color to Frankfurt default color

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to create boxes for which I can specify width, height and position at will.
For this I used the command `tcolorbox` as was suggested to me on this forum.

But I want to specify the color of the frame of my `tcolorbox` to match the default blue of the `Frankfurt` theme I'm using.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{frankfurt}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=structure]
  Some
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]